# Jquery slider do not refresh visually after .click function in a href

Tags: jquery

I want to change sliders values on click.
The values change , but the sliderdoesn't show.
If i go back and forth to this pageview the values changed.

The action is done but the sliders do not refresh after clicked the href.
When i go a page back an forwd the sliders changed in my page..

http://jsfiddle.net/K63QE/2/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#123").click(function(){
      $('#slider1').val(10);
      $('#slider1').slider('refresh');
      $('#slider2').val(20);
      $('#slider2').slider('refresh');
      $('#slider3').val(c);
      $('#slider3').slider('refresh');
      $('#slider4').val(d);
      $('#slider4').slider('refresh');
      $('#slider5').val(e);
      $('#slider5').slider('refresh');
      $('#slider6').val(f);
      $('#slider6').slider('refresh');
      $('#slider7').val(g);
      $('#slider7').slider('refresh');
      $('#slider8').val(h);
      $('#slider8').slider('refresh');
      $('#slider9').val(i);
      $('#slider9').slider('refresh');
    });

  });
```

Comment: The function `showUser` does not exist in your fiddle.

Comment: yeah but shouldnt be the prob...

Answer (score 0):

I simplified the fiddle as much as I could and it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/K63QE/4/

HTML

```
<a id="link" href="#">Update Values</a>
<br>
<input type="range" name="slider" id="slider1"  min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" />
```

JS

```
$("#link").click(function(){
  $('#slider1').val(50);
});
```

So there must be another error in your code. And you don't need the `slider('refresh')` method.

Comment: I updated jsfiddle please click trough page 3 ang try to enter "Einstellungen" (settings in german).
http://jsfiddle.net/UJ8Rc/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding single quotes to the slider value. Change this code :

```
$('#slider1').val(10);
```

to this:

```
$('#slider1').val('10');
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in your fiddle, you didn't load the jQuery library, have multiple element with the same ID ('sliderplek') and you rewrite `<script>`. These may not be a problem in your local machine but since I can only see your fiddle they have to be fixed. Once these are fixed, I could refresh your slider.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K63QE/12/

Your problem is the `.slider('refresh')` and the other jsfiddle error I mentioned earlier.

Also, my fiddle wouldn't work beyond `#slide2` because you are passing variables which has not yet been defined.

UPDATE:

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UJ8Rc/3/

The body itself does not recognize the `showUser` function nor your variables unless you put the javascript at the head of your HTML.

For now I just alert the values from inside `showUser` function whenever you slide.

Comment: I updated jsfiddle please click trough page 3 ang try to enter "Einstellungen" (settings in german).
http://jsfiddle.net/UJ8Rc/2/

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work. I can only see text with grey circle in the middle.

Comment: You might want to update your original question with this fiddle. And what is suppose to happen in Einstellungen?